# I want to change the hint color of TextInputLayout from white to red dynamically from java code.

Tags: android, sdk

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
            android:id="@+id/input_layout_enter_first_name"
            android:layout_width="@dimen/btn_width"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/editText_height"
            android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_top_20"
            android:background="@drawable/transperent_bg"
            android:textColorHint="@color/white"
              >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/enter_first_name"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/layout_margin_left_5"
                android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/layout_margin_top_1"
                android:background="@color/transperent"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/white"
                android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                android:maxLines="1"
                android:hint="@string/enter_first_name"
                android:textColorHint="@color/white"
                android:textColor="@color/white"
                android:textSize="@dimen/textsize_12" />
        </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>



TextInputLayout input_layout_enter_first_name = (TextInputLayout) findViewById(R.id.input_layout_enter_first_name);
```

input_layout_enter_first_name.setHint(Html.fromHtml("Required!!! "));

Actually it is changing only the text dynamically but am unable to change the color into RED.

Answer (score 0):

You can set `TextInputLayout`text hint color from `style` like below:

```
TextInputLayout til = (TextInputLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.input_layout_enter_first_name);
til.setHintTextAppearance(R.style.One);
```

And style:

```
 <style name="One">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/Red</item>
</style>

<style name="Two">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/color_primary</item>
</style>
```

Set your desired color and switch between this styles anywhere you like